Hub to create hook (Webhooks API)
I want to create a webhook to register callbacks for Data Management events.
From reading the documentation, it seems that the only way to do this is by using the folderId as the scope key for the event. I was wondering if there is any way to pass a hubId in order to subscribe to the event.
I'm trying to avoid having to create a webhook every time a new folder is created and capture all events that occur within the hub.

The Data Management events supported by the webhook service are currently all limited to folder scope.
